# Why does my Julia script not show plots in Pluto?

Tags: plot, julia, pluto.jl

This is the code I'm trying to run

```
begin
    for i in 1:10:100
        display(Plots.plot(x[i:i+100]))
    end
end
```

and this is the output I get

```
Plot{Plots.GRBackend() n=1}Plot{Plots.GRBackend() n=1}Plot{Plots.GRBackend() n=1}Plot{Plots.GRBackend() n=1}Plot{Plots.GRBackend() n=1}Plot{Plots.GRBackend() n=1}Plot{Plots.GRBackend() n=1}Plot{Plots.GRBackend() n=1}Plot{Plots.GRBackend() n=1}Plot{Plots.GRBackend() n=1}
```

I'm trying to get a series of different figures that show the different slices of x that are specified in each loop. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want the output to look like? What do you mean by "a series of different figures" - are you looking for an animation, or a plot with multiple subplots, or just multiple plots in a row (somewhat like the answer from BallPointPen)?

Comment: @NilsGudat I'm expecting something like what you get with Matplotlib if you plot graphs on different figures: the two will be completely separate. Like using Figure() in Matlab.

Answer (score 5):

If, say, you wanted the graphs in a 5-by-2 grid, you could do the following:

```
[collect(row) for row in eachrow(reshape([Plots.plot(i:i+100) for i in 1:10:100], (5,:)))]
```

(I've removed `x` to avoid an undefined variable error.)

[image: Pluto graph output]

It's not ideal, so hopefully someone comes along with a better solution.

Comment: The figures would automatically look better (bigger) with the `PlotlyJS` backend.